Is there a standard formula or rule of thumb for how much airflow a whirlybird/turbine roof vent will achieve given a diameter and a wind speed?
I've been looking for effectiveness measures for whirlybird vents for a while and I can't find anything in building codes, and only one empirical claim from askthebuilder.com for a relationship between diameter, windspeed and airflow. I know there are general accepted rules like 1 square foot of ventilation per 300 square feet of roof space, but I'm really looking for a formula for airflow. Am I oversimplifying the problem? Thanks!

You want at least minimum airflow/ventilation from the roof at any windspeed even zero.  Whirlybirds probably do not increase airflow enough to make them better than other types.  You start adding moving parts to a system, you start to add up more failure points.  Just wait till the bearings start going out and find out how many neighbours have 12 gauge shotguns.

I mirror crip659's comments.  Whirlybirds used to be common in my part of Fla.  Too many failed and either bound up, or squealed like 100 6 year old girls.  Add to this an area where most homeowners were too old to get on a roof to do anything about it and an entire industry was born to remove these things and replace with ridge vents. I would not install one even if someone paid me handsomely. I know I will be called back because it failed.

@ Steve, you are not oversimplifying, you are over complicating.
